# TypeScript: Reuse function definitions in an interface definition

Tags: typescript, reusability

In the following piece of TypeScript definition code, I'd like to reuse the function type of `baz` for the `baz` property of the `Foo` interface.

```
declare module 'foo' {

  /* Not all exports will be reused in the interface. */
  export function bar(a: string): string

  /* Imagine a big and verbose function
     definition with plenty overloadings: */
  export function baz(a: number): number
  export function baz(a: Overloaded): number

  interface Foo {

    /* The interface is for a function, so I cannot use module */
    (a: string): string

    /* how do I reuse the full definition of the baz function? */
    baz

  }

  export default Foo

}
```

I have not been able to find a way to reuse the definition other than copy-paste. Is there a better way than copy-paste? It's alright if I have to define the interface first and reuse its members as static exports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type of `baz` can be reused with type computation (`typeof` and `|` in this case):

```
// Foo will contain 2 overloads of baz
type Foo = { (a: string): string; } | typeof baz;
```

However note that a `type` is somehow different to a `interface`. e.g. it can not be used in `class .. implements ..`.

Comment: Thanks! `typeof` was the answer. It should be like this to answer my particular question though: `interface Foo = { (a: string): string; baz: typeof baz }`.